# Using savebox around the BODY of environ

Tags: macros, line-breaking, environments, boxes

I tried to use a `\savebox` around the `\BODY` macro of `\NewEnviron`. Can I keep the linebreaks somehow (they are gone, in the MWE)?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{environ}

\newsavebox{\mybox}

\NewEnviron{myenv}{%
    \savebox{\mybox}{\BODY}
    \usebox{\mybox}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{myenv}
A

B
\end{myenv}

\end{document}
```

The problem is probably independent from the `environ` package but that is what I'm trying to use.

Or: Is there a way to determine the vertical and horizontal size of the `\BODY`?

Comment: Unrelated to the question: you should move `\newsavebox{\mybox}` outside of the environment's definition (try using the environment twice to see why)

Comment: The line breaks are lost because they're converted into spaces (or `\par`) as part of the tokenization stage. Moreover `\savebox` typesets its contents in horizontal mode, so you'll get a long line. Maybe you can expand your question telling what's your aim.

Comment: @egreg. I'm trying to determine the vertical and horizontal size of the output of `\BODY`. `\savebox` seemed to be the closest to this aim.

Comment: There's no "natural" horizontal size: you have to specify what you want or it will be the current `\linewidth`.

Comment: The `adjustbox` package should help you here. You need to use the `varwidth` key to get a variable width. An alternative is to use the `lrbox` environment with a `varwidth` environment inside it (needs the `varwidth` package).

Comment: Side note: if you try to use the box outside the environment you'll need to do something else: [boxes - Why is a box seemingly emptied after closing an environment - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/645089/why-is-a-box-seemingly-emptied-after-closing-an-environment)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no notion of “natural width” of a text, when paragraphs are being built: TeX will use what you specify or `\linewidth` in case you don't.

However there's the `varwidth` environment that can help:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{environ,varwidth}

\newsavebox{\mybox}

\NewEnviron{myenv}{%
  \sbox{\mybox}{\begin{varwidth}{\linewidth}\BODY\end{varwidth}}%
  The box is \texttt{\the\wd\mybox} wide
  and \texttt{\the\dimexpr\ht\mybox+\dp\mybox} high.
}

\begin{document}

\begin{myenv}
A

B
\end{myenv}

\end{document}
```

It depends on you what to do with those dimensions.

[image]

Using `\NewEnviron` is not necessary:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{varwidth}

\newsavebox{\mybox}

\newenvironment{myenv}
 {\begin{lrbox}{\mybox}
  \begin{varwidth}{\linewidth}}
 {\end{varwidth}%
  \end{lrbox}%
  The box is \texttt{\the\wd\mybox} wide and
  \texttt{\the\dimexpr\ht\mybox+\dp\mybox} high.
}

\begin{document}

\begin{myenv}
A

B
\end{myenv}

\end{document}
```