# Insert text into a fixed size box

Tags: environments, boxes

Is there a way to create a box which has fixed width and height? I tried `\parbox` and some similar things, but sometimes the text overflows.

If the text inserted would overflow: it should be resized to fit or it should be clipped (with a warning). Is any of these possible?

We can assume, that the inserted text is one continous paragraph.

Related: [Package for game/playing cards (not only poker)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/142447/package-for-game-playing-cards-not-only-poker)

Comment: Can you show us an example of `\parbox` when the text overflows? You should get an `overfull hbox` message in that case.

Comment: Related/duplicate http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26002/fit-text-into-given-box-by-adjusting-the-fontsize or http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33417/adjust-font-size-on-the-fly

Comment: There is always \resizebox

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel the overflow is vertical: `\parbox[t][2cm][t]{2cm}{\lipsum[1]}` - and there is no warning here.

Comment: @egreg: those topics are more than two years old, so they should not make this implicitly a duplicate. But thanks, I couldn't find them, but they contain useful info (+1).

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123614/making-the-text-fit-in-a-specific-space-in-latex/123650#123650

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the `fitting` library of the `tcolorbox` package. It provides a macro called `\tcboxfit` which fits the font size of the content to the dimensions of the box. Alternatively, the option `fit` for `tcolorbox` does the same trick.

Note that the used font has to be resizable to all dimensions (vector font) to achieve the correct resizing.

The first example shows a framed box (can be adapted in many ways), the second one a box without a frame (the red border is just for displaying the size), the third example displays a box with title and fixed height.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lmodern}% or any other vector / postscript font
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\tcboxfit[width=6cm,height=6cm,nobeforeafter,
  before=\noindent]{\lipsum[1]}
%
%
\begin{tcolorbox}[fit,width=6cm,height=6cm,blank,
  borderline={0.4pt}{0pt}{red!20!white},
  watermark text={6cm $\times$ 6cm},nobeforeafter]
\lipsum[1]
\end{tcolorbox}

\bigskip

\tcboxfit[height=6cm,title={This box has a height of 6cm},
  colback=blue!5!white,colframe=blue!30!black,
  before=\noindent]{\lipsum[1]}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you happen to know anything about the algorithm? Execution seems to quite slow with a number of bad boxes... :(
I think I might have to implement my own fitting algorithm.

Comment: Hm... I have to quote my doctor father: 'There is no free lunch'. You have to pay for the automatic sizing with compilation time. The algorithm is a bisection method which (by experiment) usally does not need more than a dozen steps. The option `fix maxstep` allows to control the maximal step number (20 by default). Since the objective function is not smooth (because of line breaks) I doubt that some kind of Newton method will give stable and faster results. But, maybe, for your special application there is a faster algorithm (?).

Comment: I'd hoped for free breakfast only, and I've been served. :) I have my plans, but the implementation has to wait for a while... Thanks for this answer again anyway, it's a good-to-know-about feature.

Comment: I've got around fitting iterations with the use of a calculation and a resize. [Posted it as an answer.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/144652/36821)

Answer (score 3):

Using `tikz` or `pstricks` you can clip a portion of a graphics.

Here's an example using `tikz`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\fbox{\begin{minipage}[t][4in]{3in}
  \lipsum[1-3]
\end{minipage}}
%%
\hspace*{\fill}vs.\hspace*{\fill}
%%
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(myparbox.base)]
  \node (A) at (0,0)      {};
  \node (B) at (3in,4in)  {};

  %\draw ($(A)-(2pt,2pt)$) rectangle ($(B)+(2pt,2pt)$);
  \clip ($(A)-(2pt,2pt)$) rectangle ($(B)+(2pt,2pt)$);

  \node[below right,
        inner sep=0pt,
        outer sep=0pt,
        text width=+3in,
        align=justify] (myparbox) at (A|-B) 
    {\lipsum[1-3]};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's a similar example using `pstricks`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-node}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\fbox{\begin{minipage}[t][4in]{3in}
  \lipsum[1-3]
\end{minipage}}
%%
\hspace*{\fill}vs.\hspace*{\fill}
%%
\begin{psclip}{\psline[linestyle=none](0,3ex)(3in,3ex)(3in,-\dimexpr4in-1ex\relax)(0,-\dimexpr4in-1ex\relax)}
  \begin{minipage}[t]{3in}
    \lipsum[1-3]
   \end{minipage}
\end{psclip}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The `text width` options does install a `minipage` on its own. So you can just do `\node[below right, text width=+3in] at (A|-B) {\lipsum[1-3]};`.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Thanks for your comment, but when I try `text width=+3in`, the linebreaks are not consistent with that produced using a `minipage` set to the same width.  Do you know why?

Comment: If I add `align=justify`, they are the same.

Comment: Thanks. For the record: clipping warning can be generated by measuring the size using [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/144252/36821).

Answer (score 2):

I've made my own solution, without iterations. Can still be improved with some iterations or similar. `epsilon` is for tweaking, and `\fitfuzz` defines the warning threshold.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[latin]{babel} % demo only: for hyphenation in lipsum
\usepackage{lipsum} % demo only
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}

\newsavebox{\mybox}
\newlength{\actheight}
\newlength{\prefwidth}
\newlength{\prefheight}

\def\fitfuzz{1000} % hundredth of a percent

\newlength{\scaleepsilon}
\setlength{\scaleepsilon}{0pt}

\makeatletter
\def\fitbox#1#2#3{%
\setlength{\prefwidth@fitbox}{#1}%
\setlength{\prefheight@fitbox}{#2}%
\sbox{\mybox@fitbox}{\hbadness=10000\parbox[b]{\prefwidth@fitbox}{#3}}%
\setlength{\actheight@fitbox}{\the\dimexpr\ht\mybox@fitbox+\dp\mybox@fitbox}%
\edef\valueA{\strip@pt\prefwidth@fitbox}%
\edef\valueB{\strip@pt\prefheight@fitbox}%
\edef\valueBx{\strip@pt\actheight@fitbox}%
\edef\valueE{\strip@pt\scaleepsilon@fitbox}%
\FPeval\valueAx{pow(0.5,\valueBx*\valueA*\valueA/\valueB)+\valueE}%
\sbox{\mybox@fitbox}{\hbadness=10000\parbox{\valueAx pt}{#3}}%
\setlength{\actheight@fitbox}{\the\dimexpr\ht\mybox@fitbox+\dp\mybox@fitbox}%
\edef\valueBx{\strip@pt\actheight@fitbox}%
\FPeval\badness{round(10000*abs(1-\valueBx/\valueAx/\valueB*\valueA):0)}%
\FPifgt{\badness}{\fitfuzz}%
    \@latex@warning{Notably inaccurate fitting (badness \badness)}%
\fi%
\resizebox{\prefwidth@fitbox}{\prefheight@fitbox}{\parbox[b]{\valueAx pt}{#3}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\fitbox{3cm}{5cm}{\lipsum[1]}\includegraphics[width=3cm, height=5cm]{}

\includegraphics[width=3cm, height=5cm]{}

\fitbox{4cm}{3cm}{\lipsum[2]}\includegraphics[width=4cm, height=3cm]{}

\includegraphics[width=4cm, height=3cm]{}

\end{document}
```

Thanks to the [answer of egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/144615/36821).

Comment: Just to do some nitpicking: I would count this solution as 3 iterations since 3 parboxes are constructed, plus a resizebox which may be cheaper(?). But, of course, it is faster than doing more iterations (8 or 10) without resizebox :-)

Comment: @ThomasF.Sturm agreed. And I like the that there are no `Underfull` and `Overfull \hbox` messages when it's unnecessary.

Comment: Yes, you are right. The unnecessary messages are removed with `tcolorbox` version `2.60 (2013/12/17)` ... :-).

Comment: @ThomasF.Sturm thanks for the info. I haven't noticed until now that you are the package maintainer. :)