# Can I disable underfull \hbox messages for a specific line?

Tags: spacing, boxes, warnings

The line `\sbox{\mybox}{\parbox{2cm}{\lipsum[1]}}` causes some of the above messages (59):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newsavebox{\mybox}

\begin{document}

\sbox{\mybox}{\parbox{2cm}{\lipsum[1]}}

\end{document}
```

Do I need to fix them? If not: is it possible disable these messages for that line?

Comment: I don't think you should suppress them - it is valuable information.  Perhaps your box contents should be `{\raggedright\lipsum[1]}` instead.

Comment: @AndrewSwann Why is it useful if I don't have a `\usebox`? The effect is the same with `\raggedright`.

Comment: With `\raggedright` I get not underfull messages.  Can you tell us why would you want to save this material if you are not going to issue a `\usebox`.

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to do, but you can use `\hbadness=10000` before `\sbox` to avoid the warnings...

Comment: @AndrewSwann I wanted to use the height for calculations, as egreg said it in his answer

Comment: @masu I had no time at that moment to make it an answer. egreg has explained it better than I could have done, so thanks anyway.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

TeX displays such warnings when the badness is above a threshold contained in the parameters `\hbadness` and `\vbadness`. You're interested in the first one:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newsavebox{\mybox}

\begin{document}

\sbox{\mybox}{\hbadness=10000 \parbox{2cm}{\lipsum[1]}}

\end{document}
```

Since the badness can never be above 10000, this effectively suppresses all `Underfull \hbox` messages. There might still be `Overfull \hbox` messages, which are suppressed by adding `\hfuzz=\maxdimen` *inside* the `\parbox`.

If the constructed box is used only for measuring it, these actions can be justified. Since the change to the parameters happens in a group, the values will automatically be restored at the end.

Comment: May I bother with another question? I don't think that opening a new question is the right way. Are there pitfalls in using `\hbadness=10000` inside `\resizebox`? Can I lose anything useful there? I don't really see the point of an `underfull \hbox` message inside a `resizebox`.

Comment: @masu If you want to *use* the box, then messages are useful. If you only want to test whether it fits, then they are only distracting; but for the final setting I'd leave the normal value of `\hbadness` so as to know whether the typesetting is good or not.

Comment: I use the resizebox without a `savebox`. But I couldn't figure out how can a warning be useful inside `resizebox`. Or is it the error of `resizebox` itself even if `\hbadness=10000` is specified inside it?

Comment: @masu I don't understand what you're talking about. If a box is badly typeset it remains such also if resized.

Comment: By the way, I used your answer to construct [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/144652/36821).