# How to avoid frame break in beamer?

Tags: beamer, page-breaking

I am using the command `\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]` to split a large slide into multiple slides. However, the last slide only contains two lines and I would like to force them into the previous slide. How can I do so?

Comment: Please see here http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/145401/34618 for your reference.

Comment: Well, I think is better to fix manually the amount of information per slide when you use `allowframebreaks` in that case you can distribute it better.

Comment: @Jesse Thanks for the help. I managed to do the trick by using the columns environment.

Comment: @Aradnix This problem pertains to the bibliography part so in order to retain consecutive numbering I resorted to a trick like this. I think you suggest against using `allowframebreaks`, am I right?

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is to have two slides where there is no frametitle in the second one:

```
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Lorem ipsun}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
Lorem Ipsun. 
\end{frame}
```

In this way, you kind of visually "break" one slide into many slides.

Other ways which affects the visual appearance are

- make text smaller
- to put more text in the same space - tables

However, I like the "no-frametitle" option most, since it is most flexible.