# How to reduce font size automatically to prevent new line in cell

Tags: fontsize, tabularx

I use tabularx environment, where `\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX}`. When I inserted in every tabulars long numbers, cell splits for two lines and my table looks like very ugly. This long numbers will be inserted automatically. Is it possible to recalculate font size automatically If cell value is longer and doesn't fit ?

Here my source

```
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{XXXXXXXXXXX}
0&1 &2 &3 &4 &5 &6 &7 &8 &9 &10\\
\hline
4444444 &4444444 &4444444 &4444444 &4444444 &4444444 &4444444 &4444444 &4444444 &4444444\\
\hline
4444444 &4444444 &4444444 &4444444 &4444444 &4444444 &4444444 &4444444 &4444444 &4444444\\
\hline
4444444 &4444444 &4444444 &4444444 &4444444 &4444444 &4444444 &4444444 &4444444 &4444444\\
\end{tabularx}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Usually, we don't put a
greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange
at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of
our trying to keep everything very concise.
[Accepting and upvoting answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about)
is the preferred way here to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: The `fitbox` [I've created](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/144652/36821) might help you to do that (but you only need to resize, if the content is too large). Although the "cell by cell automatization" is a tough nut to crack - I don't if it's even possible.

Comment: Do you really want to shrink or if these are output from an arbitrary precision integer package or similar, you could allow linebreaking between digits (either way `tabularx` isn't really helping, it is designed for paragraphs of text with multiple potential linebreaking points)

Comment: No, I need in shrink of font, because system, which output my template table, inserts ready value like format xx.xx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's generally a bad idea to apply scaling to text as it leads to inconsistent font sizes but if you must, you must:

Don't use `tabularx` just set the table natural size then scale it (`graphicx` package).

```
\noindent\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{*{11}{l}}
0&1 &2 &3 &4 &5 &6 &7 &8 &9 &10\\
\hline
4444444 &4444444 &4444444 &4444444 &4444444 &4444444 &4444444 &4444444 &4444444 &4444444\\
\hline
4444444 &4444444 &4444444 &4444444 &4444444 &4444444 &4444444 &4444444 &4444444 &4444444\\
\hline
4444444 &4444444 &4444444 &4444444 &4444444 &4444444 &4444444 &4444444 &4444444 &4444444\\
\end{tabular}}
```