# resizebox doesn't resize a tabular vertically

Tags: tables, scaling

Why is that? Shouldn't they both be `2cm`x`2cm` in size?!

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\resizebox{2cm}{2cm}{\rule{6cm}{7cm}}
\resizebox{2cm}{2cm}{\begin{tabular}{l l}A&B\\C&D\end{tabular}}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You want `\resizebox*` not `\resizebox` the latter scales the *height* whereas the former scales *height* + *depth*. A tabular is vertically centred so the height is half its vertical extent.

Answer (score 3):

I do not know why, but:

1) If you want to have proper dimensions, use:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\resizebox{2cm}{2cm}{\rule{6cm}{7cm}}
%\resizebox{2cm}{2cm}{\begin{tabular}{l l}A&B\\C&D\end{tabular}}
\resizebox{2cm}{2cm}{\begin{tabular}[b]{|l l|}\hline A&B\\C&D\\  \hline\end{tabular}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

2) If you want to see a horror, please change `[b]` onto `[t]`. I know that it is not a proper answer, but one should to see THAT! :-)

Comment: [b] is closer but not what is wanted, as with b more of the total vertical extent is in the height, but the depth of the bottom row is not taken into account. with [t] you are scaling by 2cm/\ht\strutbox which is rather a bigger scale than intended, probably. (actually with an \hline at the bottom, the reference point is at the bottom so you get lucky:-)

Comment: It have useful info (+1) (but I'm going to accept David's answer). I've seen weirder stuff than the one you mentioned in 2) when I used `parbox` and `minipage` in resizebox while I was trying to construct an answer for [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/144299/insert-text-into-a-fixed-size-box).

Comment: @masu the situation with parbox is identical to that with tabular, normally it has height and depth and resizebox scales the height.