# How to make a box with fixed size?

Tags: boxes

`\parbox[pos][height][contentpos]{width}{text}` gives me a box where `height` is actually "minimal height", while `width`= exact width. I would like height to also be "exact height". How can I do this? Text that is larger then the content should

1. disappear "within the box" and not appear outside the boxes borders or
2. be adjusted in size so that it fits into the box.

Though I think 2 is asking to much.

Here is how far I got:

```
\RequirePackage[l2tabu, orthodox]{nag}      % Warning when old or wrong commands are used
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}             % permits Computer Modern fonts at arbitrary sizes
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,oneside]{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lmodern}% or any other vector / postscript font
\usepackage{lipsum}

\geometry{
    a4paper,
    centering,
    hmargin=0.5mm,
    vmargin=1mm,
    ignoreall,
    showframe
}

\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{ngerman}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\pagestyle{empty}

\newcommand{\myboxI}{%
\fbox{\adjustbox{totalheight=21.2mm, width=52.5mm, keepaspectratio, rotate=0, minipage=[r][21.2mm][t]{52.5mm}}{%
    wefewf wwkeföjwlkej fkewjf ölkewjflkewjf \\ ölkewjf lwkejf lkwjlkwejf lkwejf \\ asdf wef we \\ werwer we \\ werwerewfewfewfewfewfwef wef ewf ewf wef we f \\ wefewf wefwe%
}}%
}

\newcommand{\myboxII}{%
\begin{tcolorbox}[%
  fit,width=52.5mm,height=21.2mm,blank,
  borderline={0.4pt}{0pt}{red!20!white},
  %watermark text={6cm $\times$ 6cm},nobeforeafter
  ]
  wefewf wwkeföjwlkej fkewjf ölkewjflkewjf \\ ölkewjf lwkejf lkwjlkwejf lkwejf \\ asdf wef we \\ werwer we \\ werwerewfewfewfewfewfwef wef ewf ewf wef we f \\ wefewf wefwe
\end{tcolorbox}%
}

\myboxI\hspace{-1cm}\hfill\myboxI\hspace{-1cm}\hfill\myboxI\hspace{-1cm}\hfill\myboxI

\bigskip

\myboxII\hspace{-1cm}\hfill\myboxII\hspace{-1cm}\hfill\myboxII\hspace{-1cm}\hfill\myboxII

\end{document}
```

[image]

The first attempt does not really scale the content, as I had hoped. Also I had expected that the boxes are just next to each other, not overlap.

The second does not allow the boxes to be next to each other.

Comment: For problem 2, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/144299/insert-text-into-a-fixed-size-box

Comment: you can enforce a "uniform" height for the normal text size by placing a `\strut` at the beginning of the text in the box, and another at the end of that text (no intervening space) to mimic the normal baselines and ensure the depth of descenders in the bottom line.

Comment: Also for problem 2, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123614/making-the-text-fit-in-a-specific-space-in-latex

Comment: There is no point in loading `fix-cm` if you load `lmodern` that I know of.

Answer (score 4):

Problem 2 is treated elsewhere on the site, I'll deal only with problem 1, which can be solved with `\vsplit`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\box_new:N \l_hideparbox_box

\NewDocumentCommand{\hideparbox}{O{c}mm+m}
 {% #1=alignment, #2=height, #3=width, #4=text
  \group_begin:
  \vbox_set:Nn \l_hideparbox_box
   {
    \use:c { @parboxrestore }
    \hsize=#3\scan_stop:
    \strut#4\par
   }
  \vbadness=\c_ten_thousand % no spurious underfull messages
  \vbox_set_split_to_ht:NNn \l_hideparbox_box \l_hideparbox_box { #2 }
  \parbox[#1][#2]{#3}
   {
    \vbox_unpack:N \l_hideparbox_box
   }
  \group_end:
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\fboxsep=0pt % just for the example

\fbox{\hideparbox{3cm}{7cm}{\lipsum*[1]}}
\fbox{\hideparbox{6cm}{7cm}{\lipsum*[1]}}

\fbox{\hideparbox[t]{3cm}{7cm}{\lipsum*[1]}}
\fbox{\hideparbox[t]{6cm}{7cm}{\lipsum*[1]}}

\fbox{\hideparbox[b]{3cm}{7cm}{\lipsum*[1]}}
\fbox{\hideparbox[b]{6cm}{7cm}{\lipsum*[1]}}

\end{document}
```

I load `microtype` just for convenience, in order to minimize overfull boxes. Also `\fbox` is used just for showing the boundaries of the boxes.

The idea is to typeset the box and then prune off everything beyond the stated limit.

[image]

Comment: 1) How do I get rid of the white space between the boxes? 2) I tried to solve problem 2 - as shown in my edited question - but not with enough success, yet... 3) How can make a white margin *inside* of the boxes?

Comment: @Make42 That's the end of line; I left it for better separating the boxes. Since the two problems are independent, it's better having two separate questions.

Comment: I forgot that the end-of-line creates whitespace - now it works. But why does this not go for my solution 2 attempt from my question? (Also, can you help 2) and 3)? Or where you referring to 3) being a separate question?)

Comment: The same problem with the white horizontally, I have vertically as well.

Comment: @Make42 I already suggested to bring problem 2 into another question.

Comment: (Sad to see, nobody had upvoted yet…)  In the `\vbox_set:Nn` command: `\unskip\strut\par` after `#4` as well?

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti That's not necessary: it's not known where the break will happen. Maybe a correction after the `\unvbox`, but I don't think it's necessary.

Comment: Yes, you are right: it is not only not necessary, it is wrong!

Comment: What is this syntax btw? How did you come up with that? Haven't seen anything like it so far.

Comment: @Make42 It's expl3. Not really necessary here, but handy when optional arguments are involved

Answer (score 3):

My solutions answers both requirements.

The implementation version A creates a box which hides text which does not fit into the box.

The implementation version B creates a box where the text is adjusted to the box dimensions.

For both cases, I used a inner white margin of 1mm.

```
\RequirePackage[l2tabu, orthodox]{nag}      % Warning when old or wrong commands are used
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}             % permits Computer Modern fonts at arbitrary sizes
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,oneside]{article}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lmodern}% or any other vector / postscript font
\usepackage{lipsum}

\geometry{
    a4paper,
    centering,
    hmargin=0.0mm,
    vmargin=1mm,
    ignoreall,
    showframe
}

\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{ngerman}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\pagestyle{empty}

\textbf{Version A: Text disappears:}

\newtcbox{\myboxA}{blank,boxsep=1mm,
  clip upper,minipage,
  width=52.5mm,height=21.2mm,nobeforeafter,
  borderline={0.4pt}{0pt}{blue!20!white},
  }

\myboxA{%
  wefewf wwkeföjwlkej fkewjf ölkewjflkewjf \\ ölkewjf lwkejf lkwjlkwejf lkwejf \\ asdf wef we \\ werwer we \\ werwerewfewfewfewfewfwef wef ewf ewf wef we f \\ wefewf wefwe%
}%
\myboxA{%
  wefewf wwkeföjwlkej fkewjf ölkewjflkewjf \\ ölkewjf lwkejf lkwjlkwejf lkwejf \\ asdf wef we \\ werwer we \\ werwerewfewfewfewfewfwef wef ewf ewf wef we f \\ wefewf wefwe%
}%
\myboxA{%
  wefewf wwkeföjwlkej fkewjf ölkewjflkewjf \\ ölkewjf lwkejf lkwjlkwejf lkwejf \\ asdf wef we \\ werwer we \\ werwerewfewfewfewfewfwef wef ewf ewf wef we f \\ wefewf wefwe%
}%
\myboxA{%
  wefewf wwkeföjwlkej fkewjf ölkewjflkewjf \\ ölkewjf lwkejf lkwjlkwejf lkwejf \\ asdf wef we \\ werwer we \\ werwerewfewfewfewfewfwef wef ewf ewf wef we f \\ wefewf wefwe%
}%


\bigskip
\textbf{Version B: Text adjusted in size:}

\newtcbox{\myboxB}{blank,boxsep=1mm,
  clip upper,fit,fit algorithm=hybrid*,
  width=52.5mm,height=21.2mm,nobeforeafter,
  borderline={0.4pt}{0pt}{red!20!white},
  }

\myboxB{%
  wefewf wwkeföjwlkej fkewjf ölkewjflkewjf \\ ölkewjf lwkejf lkwjlkwejf lkwejf \\ asdf wef we \\ werwer we \\ werwerewfewfewfewfewfwef wef ewf ewf wef we f \\ wefewf wefwe%
}%
\myboxB{%
  wefewf wwkeföjwlkej fkewjf ölkewjflkewjf \\ ölkewjf lwkejf lkwjlkwejf lkwejf \\ asdf wef we \\ werwer we \\ werwerewfewfewfewfewfwef wef ewf ewf wef we f \\ wefewf wefwe%
}%
\myboxB{%
  wefewf wwkeföjwlkej fkewjf ölkewjflkewjf \\ ölkewjf lwkejf lkwjlkwejf lkwejf \\ asdf wef we \\ werwer we \\ werwerewfewfewfewfewfwef wef ewf ewf wef we f \\ wefewf wefwe%
}%
\myboxB{%
  wefewf wwkeföjwlkej fkewjf ölkewjflkewjf \\ ölkewjf lwkejf lkwjlkwejf lkwejf \\ asdf wef we \\ werwer we \\ werwerewfewfewfewfewfwef wef ewf ewf wef we f \\ wefewf wefwe%
}%


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Guess I should really learn `tcolorbox`...