# Why is a box seemingly emptied after closing an environment

Tags: environments, boxes

I'm attempting to fill a box, within an environment, to be used after the environment is closed, similar to how `\begin{lrbox}{\boxname} ... \end{lrbox}` works. However, for some reason it seems that after closing the environment the content of the box is gone.

```
\newsavebox{\somebox}

\newenvironment{myenv}
{
    \begin{lrbox}{\somebox}
}{
    \end{lrbox}
    \usebox{\somebox} % This works
}

\begin{myenv}
    Something
\end{myenv}

\usebox{\somebox} % This doesn't
```

In the example above `\usebox{\somebox}` within `myenv`'s closing block seems to work as expected, but not if used after `\end{myenv}`. Maybe there is some fundamental understanding of environments and/or boxes that I am missing, but I would expect what I am trying to do to be possible, since it's how the `lrbox` environment works?

Comment: The whole idea of environments is that their work occurs in their own group (as if the code were surrounded by `{...}`.  Thus, by design, what happens in the environment is inaccessible to the outside code, unless the environment saves its content globally.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Right, I see. Indeed adding ``\global\sbox{\somebox}{\usebox{\somebox}}`` within the closing brace of ``myenv`` makes the content available after ``\end{myenv}``. I guess the ``lrbox`` environment must be doing something similar to that?

Comment: Yes, except that it is not `lrbox` that is "at fault", but the environment `myenv` which isolates the original `lrbox` operation from the main code.

Comment: Right, makes sense. I guess I got confused expecting the ``lrbox`` behavior to be the default. I think I follow now, thanks!

Comment: the definition of lrbox is uniquely coded by hand avoiding all the normal environment forms, so that it works as you describe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The whole idea of environments is that their work occurs in their own group (as if the code were surrounded by `{...}`. Thus, by design, what happens in the environment is inaccessible to the outside code, unless the environment saves its content globally.

As the OP concluded from my comment, the content can be made accessible by globally saving the content of `\somebox` before leaving the environment.  David recommends using a `\setbox`, rather than `\sbox`, as a reliable way to make the assignment global:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newsavebox{\somebox}

\newenvironment{myenv}
{
    \begin{lrbox}{\somebox}
}{
    \end{lrbox}
    \usebox{\somebox} % This works
    \global\setbox\somebox=\hbox{\usebox{\somebox}}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{myenv}
    Something
\end{myenv}

\usebox{\somebox} % This now works with \somebox globally saved

\end{document}
```

The issue is not that the `lrbox` prevents its work from re-use, but that the closing of `myenv` effectively isolates the `lrbox` from the main code.

Comment: `\global\sbox` is not guaranted to work. It may accidentally but most latex assignments, `lrbox`, `\newcommand`, `\setlength`... can not be prefixed  with `\global`

Comment: So, what would you suggest, @DavidCarlisle, to globalize it instead?

Comment: use `\setbox` the primitive, or an L3 global box ssignment)

Comment: That is good to know, @DavidCarlisle.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Boxes are assigned locally by LaTeX, so after the end of `myenv` the assignment is lost.

```
\newsavebox{\somebox}% for global assignment
\newsavebox{\someboxinternal}% for local assignment
\newenvironment{myenv}
 {%
  \begin{lrbox}{\someboxinternal}%
 }
 {%
  \end{lrbox}%
  \global\setbox\somebox=\hbox{\unhbox\someboxinternal}%
  %\usebox{\somebox}% <-- if you want to use it inside myenv
 }
```

What's the difference between this and [Steven's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/645092/4427)?

1. the box register `\somebox` is only assigned globally: local and global assignments to the same register should be avoided
2. there is no added level of boxing like in `\global\setbox\somebox=\hbox{\usebox{\somebox}}`

If I run

```
\showboxbreadth=1000 \showboxdepth=1000
\tracingonline=1
\documentclass{article}

\newsavebox{\somebox}% for global assignment
\newsavebox{\someboxinternal}% for local assignment
\newenvironment{myenv}
 {%
  \begin{lrbox}{\someboxinternal}%
 }
 {%
  \end{lrbox}%
  \global\setbox\somebox=\hbox{\unhbox\someboxinternal}%
  %\usebox{\somebox}% <-- if you want to use it inside myenv
 }

\begin{document}

\begin{myenv}
abc
\end{myenv}

\showbox\somebox

\stop
```

the console shows

```
> \box50=
\hbox(6.94444+0.0)x15.27782
.\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 a
.\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 b
.\kern0.27779
.\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 c
```

If I replace the global assignment with

```
\global\setbox\somebox=\hbox{\usebox\someboxinternal}%
```

the console shows

```
> \box50=
\hbox(6.94444+0.0)x15.27782
.\hbox(6.94444+0.0)x15.27782
..\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 a
..\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 b
..\kern0.27779
..\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 c
```

and you see the nesting.

Answer (score 2):

The reason of the problem (LaTeX environment creates a group) was mentioned in another answers. You can use only TeX primitives, it gives you much more control what is done:

```
\newbox\somebox

\def\myenv{\global\setbox\somebox\hbox\bgroup\bgroup\ignorespaces}
\def\endmyenv{\unskip\egroup\egroup}

\begin{myenv}
    Something
\end{myenv}

\box\somebox % This does
```

The double `\bgroup` and `\egoup` is here because of LaTeX's color management.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a fan of the environ package, so I will add my version based on Steven's one.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{environ} 
 
\begin{document}

\newsavebox{\somebox} 

\NewEnviron{myenv}{ 
\begin{lrbox}{\somebox} 
\BODY
\end{lrbox} 
\usebox{\somebox}
\global\setbox\somebox=\hbox{\usebox{\somebox}}
} 

Abc
\begin{myenv} Something \end{myenv} 


Def
\usebox{\somebox} 

If you only want to reuse stuff, you can go like this:

\NewEnviron{myenvII}{
\global\let\mycmd\BODY
\mycmd
} 

\begin{myenvII} Another thing \end{myenvII}

\mycmd

\end{document}
```